# Update a template after state changes using non-vuex state management

Tags: javascript, vue.js, state

I am making an app which increments a value when you click a `+` button.

I am following the [example from the documentation on Simple State Management](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html#ad).

I have set up an event handling method which increments a state value. This is triggered when a button is clicked. It updates the state value, but the template doesn't update.

To prove this, I have set up console logs in my `increment` function that fire and reflect the state value as expected. However, the value in the DOM never changes:

[image: 0 value in dom while value changes in console]

I have tried referring to the `counterValue` in the template as `state.counterValue` and `store.state.counterValue` but I get console errors for this.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my template:

```
<template>
<div>
  <h1>{{store.state.counterValue}}</h1>
  <button v-on:click="increment">+</button>
</div>
</template>
```

Here is my script:

```
<script>
const store = {
  debug: true,
  state: {
    counterValue: 0
  },
  increment() {
    console.log('updating counterValue...')
    this.state.counterValue = this.state.counterValue + 1
    console.log(this.state.counterValue)
  }
}
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      counterValue: store.state.counterValue
    }
  },
  methods: {
    increment: function() {
      store.increment()
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Problem With `{{store.state.counterValue}}`

From the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Text)

> The mustache tag will be replaced with the value of the msg property on the corresponding data object.

Your data object (i.e. the component/vue-instance) does not have a property named `store`. To access `const store`, you need to proxy it through the component:

```
data() {
  return {
    store: store
  }
},
```

### The Problem With `counterValue: store.state.counterValue`

This sets `this.counterValue` equal to the initial value of `store.state.counterValue`. But there is no code keeping them in sync. So, when `store.state.counterValue` changes, `counterValue` will remain the same.

---

### Solution

Proxy `const store` through the component as explained above. Example:

```js
const store = {
  debug: true,
  state: {
    counterValue: 0
  },
  increment() {
    console.log('updating counterValue...')
    this.state.counterValue = this.state.counterValue + 1
    console.log(this.state.counterValue)
  }
}
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      store: store
    }
  },
  methods: {
    increment: function() {
      this.store.increment();
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.4/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h1>{{store.state.counterValue}}</h1>
  <button v-on:click="increment">+</button>
</div>
```